# The Windows 8 News app is popping up alerts. How do I make it stop?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, popups, alert

Lately I've noticed that while I'm doing other things on my Windows 8 PC, the Windows 8 News app will pop up an alert in the upper-right corner now and then about a news story.

How do I turn that off?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open the `PC Settings` menu by hovering/touching in the lower right hand corner or pressing `Windows Key + C` and selecting the `Settings` charm, followed by selecting `Change PC Settings` from the very bottom of the menu.

Then select `Notifications` from the `PC Settings` menu.  Scroll down the `Show notifications from these apps` list until you find the `News` application and slide the selection switch to `Off`.

Comment: Beautiful!  I had no idea that setting was there.  Thanks!

Comment: In Windows 8.1 you need to select ``Search and apps`` in the ``PC settings`` menu to find the ``Notifications`` option.